# Configuring a production Angular application with file

Tags: angular, configuration

I have to build a proof of concept angular app that will make API calls to an application (software).
My issue is that i'm testing calls on a local application and the customer application may have different settings : different entry points, different ports, etc.

I would like to be able to define those parameters and read them from a file on a production server.
I read about using environment files but i have to make the setup before building the app. I want to be able to make it after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out here is the steps to follow here :
https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration

**1. create a service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadAppConfig() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/data/appConfig.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  }

  getConfig() {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

**2. Import this service in the app.module + create a initializer function **

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';

const appInitializerFn = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return appConfig.loadAppConfig();
  };
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**In my app.component :**

```
constructor(private appConfig: AppConfigService) {
}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myConfig = this.appConfig.getConfig();
}
```

Now i can display the config data in the template or anywhere in the application. When building, the json file is also exported and we can access it !